# SQL SELECT showing records only if the number of records is greater than N

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, mysql-5.1

I have a table defined like this (MySQL 5.1):

```
CREATE TABLE mysql_test_a ( 
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
email VARCHAR(50), 
reg_date TIMESTAMP 
);
```

Sample dataset:

```
INSERT INTO `mysql_test_a` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('1', 'Marcello', 'Santucci', 'marcello@tux.net', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test_a` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('2', 'Mike', 'Santucci', 'mike@tux.net', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test_a` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('3', 'Anna Maria', 'Gabriele', 'anna.maria@gabriele.net', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test_a` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('4', 'Matilde Josefa', 'Santucci', 'matilde.josefa@tux.net', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test_a` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('5', 'Milena', 'Santucci', 'mile@tux.net', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test_a` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('6', 'Luca', 'Pensa', 'luca@pensa.net', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test_a` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('7', 'Lorenzo', 'Pensa', 'lo@pensa.net', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

I need to show records matching a certain criteria (lets suppose `lastname = 'Santucci'` ) only if the number of records is greater than a certain defined limit (lets say 2).
I tried in various way without success the most promising form was:

```
SELECT
    id,
    firstname,
    lastname
FROM
    mysql_test_a
WHERE
    lastname = 'Santucci'
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

It returns only the first record.

I would prefer to use something like this form because HAVING clause will enable the use of a parameter.

--- LATE UPDATE ---

I have to be more specific on the solution: I'm looking for something that do not deal with the inner `SELECT` and more specifically its `WHERE` clause because, as I pointed out, the one provided is pretty hypotetical (i.e. it can be quite different from this and much more complex). Of course I appreciate any other hint.

Comment: Let me explain what's wrong with your query: You are using an aggregation function (`COUNT`) without `GROUP BY`. This means you aggregate the data into a single result row. As there can be multiple are multiple 'Santucci', this would mean multiple id and firstname. You should hence not be able to select the one id and firstname. The query is invalid and MySQL should raise an exception, but doesn't (due to a misfortunate ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY setting). It picks an id and firstname arbitrarily from the rows instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that your result is

`1    Marcello    Santucci`

but you want something like this:

```
1   Marcello        Santucci
2   Mike            Santucci
4   Matilde Josefa  Santucci
5   Milena          Santucci
```

In this case, you can use this query, similar to what @Popeye suggested:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname
FROM mysql_test_a tbl
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM mysql_test_a sbq WHERE sbq.lastname  = tbl.lastname) > 2
```

or this one, based on the usage of the 'in' operator

```
SELECT * from mysql_test_a
WHERE lastname IN (
    SELECT lastname
    FROM mysql_test_a
    GROUP BY lastname
    HAVING COUNT(lastname) >2
)
```

You can add 'WHERE' clauses to limit the result to 'Santucci', but I assume that a more generic answer is of interest to you.

I have also prepared a small fiddle that you can play with http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1a727/16

Comment: looks nice but what if I need to change WHERE clause with a reference to a different field? In the real case the WHERE clause is much more complex than this. There's a way to count results of the inner SELECT and return them if they fit without need to deal with the inner query itself?

Comment: @weirdgyn it depends, both are general solutions, but you will need to adapt them. As a different solution, you could also use a view, and you could count the results from the view. I cannot imagine right now what the complexity of the query is. Furthermore, when I wrote the answer, there was no update to the question. The solution works for older versions of MySQL. If you want, you can create a new question, adding more details to it, and I will try my best to answer it. Until then, if my answer was good enough for your question, you can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sub-query in your query as follows:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname
FROM mysql_test_a a
WHERE lastname = 'Santucci'
  and (select count(1) from mysql_test_a b where b.lastname  = a.lastname) > 2
```

Comment: the condition within the extern query and that in the inner one are bound? 
In the real case the condition is not that simple....

Comment: Yes, it is corelated query.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for this:

```
SELECT 
 *
 FROM
    (SELECT 
        id, 
        firstname, 
        lastname
    FROM
        mysql_test_a
    WHERE
        lastname = 'Santucci') a,
    (SELECT 
        id, 
        firstname, 
        lastname
    FROM
        mysql_test_a
    WHERE
        lastname = 'Santucci'
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2) b
WHERE
    a.lastname = b.lastname
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, I would recommend a window count:

```
select id, firstname, lastname
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over() as cnt
    from mysql_test_a a
    where lastname = 'Santucci'
) t
where cnt > 2
```

We can generalize this to handle multiple last names at once:

```
select id, firstname, lastname
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over(partition by lastname) as cnt
    from mysql_test_a a
) t
where cnt > 2
order by lastname
```

Comment: I prefer the first formulation since in the real case I will need a more complex WHERE clause

Comment: the query you provided was working fine on mysql 8.0 but unluckly I cannot update my server to this release (it runs MySQL 5.6). BTW there's a small typo on the inner select where you put `SELECT t.*` it should have been `SELECT a.*` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient method might be `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mysql_test_a t
where lastname = 'Santucci' and
      exists (select 1
              from mysql_test_a t2 
              where t2.lastname = t.lastname and
                    t2.id <> t.id
             );
```

For performance, you want an index on `mysql_test_a(lastname)`.

Comment: what if I need to change WHERE clause with a reference to a different field?

Comment: @weirdgyn . . . You can do that, but that would be the answer to a different question.

Comment: I'm looking for a less specific solution like the window count provided by GMB .

Comment: @weirdgyn . . . (1) That doesn't work in MySQL 5.1.  (2) This answers the question that you asked.

Comment: I need to check if the MySQL server could be updated to 8.0 ... as I pointed out in my question the WHERE clause is hypotetical ... of course I could have been cleaner (that's why I added a LATE UPDATE)